# Align link text at top of image link using different CSS classes

Tags: html, css

So, I am doing my mothers small business website to save her money and learning quite a bit of CSS in the process. I'm having a small problem though, I am making a Gallery page that link to 2 different pages, I want the text at http://area25dallas.com/s/gallery.htm that is sitting next to each image (showroom and staging) (also I know the images are the same, waiting on more from the momma). I want these to be on top but when I add an `a{}` to the following CSS controlling the image rollover effect it screws up all my other links on the website.

```
 .imagedropshadow {
margin:30px;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
 }

 a:hover img.imagedropshadow {
border: solid 1px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
 }
```

Is there a way I can make an `a{}` and `a:hover{}` specific to these links and images without messing the whole CSS of the site up? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create CSS for a specific element there are several approaches you can take:

- Create a specific class for the element. `<a class="image-link"></a>`

```
   a.image-link{
      //styles go here
    }
```

- You can refer to the unique context of the link. For example if it is located inside a div with ID `content`. `<div id="content"><a></a></div>`

```
    #content a{
      //styles go here
    }
```

or if it is the only `a` that can be directly inside a `p` element `<p><a></a></p>`

```
    p > a{
      //styles go here
    }
```

When adding styles to your html it is often good to consider the scope of the CSS. Note that you can declare styles multiple times for a element. So you can could make CSS for every `a` element inside your HTML and CSS for `a` elements within a specific scope.

More on CSS Selectors:

- [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref)
- [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)
- [Net Tuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)
- [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/17/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?

```
img.imagedropshadow:hover {
border: solid 1px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content .imagedropshadow {
margin:30px;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;
 }

#content  a{
}

#content  a:hover img.imagedropshadow {
border: solid 1px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
 }
```

Ideally you should put a div around your images with a class or ID and use that ID/class value to select the anchor (a{}) tags you need. I just picked the ID of the container DIV

Comment: Ah I see! I am still having trouble with getting the text to be on top of the images but I'm sure I can figure that out with some google'ing, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, When you are making your selectors really specific, such as #Content .myDiv a.link instead of #Content a.link, the more specific overrules the less-specific.

Just a tip